# Limits with Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, taylor-expansion, substitution

I'm stuck computing these two limits using Taylor series. 
The first is
1) $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\log[\sin(x)]}$$

and the second one is 
2) $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(\pi/2) - x\arctan(x)}{1}$$

I tried using the already known Taylor series, in both the two limits (and I also tried using higher orders) but I don't seem to get anywhere.
For example,  in the second limit doing a sobstitution that seems obvious to me 
 $$\{x\to \frac{1}{t}$$
 leads to 
$$\lim_{t\to 0} {\frac{1}{t}\left [\frac{\pi}{2} -\frac {1}{t} +\frac{3}{t^3} -\frac{5}{t^5} +\frac{o\left(t^5\right)}{1}\right]}$$
that is the same form I had at the beginning. Using an higher grade of the Taylor expansion doesn't change this form. 
I'm probably missing something. Can someone please explain to me what has to be done or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which Taylor series did you try in the first question?

Comment: I tried to obtain one for $$\cos^2(x)$$, and I used the Mc Laurin series for log(x+1) and sin(x), adjusting the argument in a way that they can be used in the origin. You just made me realize, I'm not sure the one I one I used for  $$\cos^2(x)$$ is fine. I used Mc Laurin without adjusting the argument. Could be why I 'm not getting the result?

Comment: What i use for this type of limit is putting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+h$ and i will make $h$ tend to $0$ using taylor series around $0$. Hoping it can help you

Comment: @AliceSegantini  If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the first**

consider:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\cos^2 x}{\log \sin x }=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 y}{\log \cos y }$$

since:

$\sin^2 y=y^2+o(y^2)$

$\cos y=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+o(y^2)$

$\log \cos y=\log\left(1-\frac{y^2}{2}+o(y^2)\right)=-\frac{y^2}{2}+o(y^2)$

we have

$$\frac{\sin^2 y}{\log \cos y }=\frac{y^2+o(y^2)}{-\frac{y^2}{2}+o(y^2)}=\frac{1+o(1)}{-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)}\to -2$$

**For the second**

$$\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac1x$$

$$x\frac{\pi}{2}- x\arctan(x)=x\arctan\frac1x=x\cdot\frac1x+o(1)\to 1$$

**NOTE**

For both limits is not strictly necessary use Taylor's expansion, It suffices use standard limits.

Comment: Sorry, I copied a wrong denominator in the second limit.  it is       
  $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(\pi/2) - x\arctan(x)}{1}$$                                            
 I'm sorry for the mistake. With that x at the denominator it's kinda easier though :) thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome, If I can, I would suggest to practice at first with easy limits using stamdard methods in order to can decide whether Taylor is necessary or not and in case it is to acquire the feeling to decide at which order to expand.

Comment: Another hint: when limits are not in 0 or $+\infty$ often it is convenient to convert by a change of variable in order to have limit at 0 or $+\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x-\frac{\pi}{2}=t.$

Hence,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2x}{\ln\sin{x}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin^2t}{\ln\cos{t}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{-2\sin^2\frac{t}{2}}{\ln\left(1-2\sin^2\frac{t}{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{\sin^2t}{-2\sin^2\frac{t}{2}}\right)=-2$$ because $\sin{t}=t-\frac{t^3}{6}+...$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using Lopital's rule:
$$L=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{-2\sin x \cos x}{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}=-2\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2 x=-2.$$
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=1.$$